# EJB 3.1 @Asynchronous really slow

Tags: performance, jakarta-ee, asynchronous, ejb-3.1

I was curious to know if anyone had used the @Asynchronous in their Java EE project(s)?

I compared a call for an async method within an EJB with the same code but from a "sync" method. The async takes 10 minutes whereas the "sync" method takes 23 seconds!!

The async method returns a Future.

Have you experienced this kind of huge performance bottleneck?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, never experienced it. We use tons of @Asynchronous methods and the execution time of code within such method is equal to a synchronous call.

One thing to be aware of is that @Asynchronous runs in its own transaction, so maybe you are somehow affected by that. This also means that a persistence context, if you happen to use one, will not propagate into such method and depending on how hot your l1 cache is prior to the load you *might* be doing a lot of additional queries to your back-end.

Also, is the 10 minutes measured from the moment you start your call until the Future returns a result, or from within the method itself?